# [arara]: clean option does not remove .xml file extensions

Tags: arara

The `clean` option of `arara` removes all extensions except for
`.xml` files when `.xml` is listed in the extensions options:

```
%  arara: clean : { extensions: [aux,bbl,bcf,blg,glg,glo,gls,idx,ilg,ind,ist,log,lof,lol,lot,out,ptc,toc,xml] }
```

leaves file `<filename>.run.xml`.

Answer (score 3):

`arara` does not use a wildcard before its extensions.

It specifically looks for
`<filname>.<extension>`
and not
`<filname>*.<extension>` where `*` means wildcard.

Wildcard translates to:
`<filname><anythingElseOrNothing>.<extension>`.

Thus `xml` should be more specific and changed to `run.xml` to get rid of the file.

.

```
Change:

%  arara: clean: { extensions [aux,< ... ... ... >,toc,xml] }

to:

%  arara: clean: { extensions [aux,< ... ... ... >,toc,run.xml] }
```